# Can we use Windows 10 (for phone ) model design in Windows phone 8.1 App?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10

I am developing an app for windows phone 8.1 . Based on MSDN design guidelines I am using  pivots and panorama controls in my application.

I heard there are some significant changes in UI in windows 10 OS and MSFT is not using popular controls like pivot and panorama in Windows 10.

MSFT uses buttons ,top bar, hamburger menu etc. mostly in their new OS version. See the [link](http://windowsphonedaily.com/2015/01/modern-ui-comparison-windows-10-versus-windows-phone-8-1.html#.VT9-ByHvOUk)

My questions is , can we design my new application in 'windows 10' model ? (using hamburger,top bar etc.) . I want to make sure they will put my app  in store. I am afraid of certification failure (there is a chance for rejection because app may not follow WP 8.1 app design guidelines)

This is actually a big app and need at least 8 months to get done .

Comment: Actually microsoft is very tolerant in approving apps, they do not have much apps, therefore rejecting big app is very unlikely - even if it does not follow guidelines. And rejecting 8.1 for following 10 guidelines? I cant imagine that happening :).

Comment: Things are not decided yet ! It's just in beta stage so we can't assume that's going to be the design in windows 10. I think, this is not much of a violation so it's gets passed for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those design guidelines are not certification requirements, they're just here to help you get a clue of WP design principles. There are some UI requirements for publication, but those are more semantic (i.e. text on buttons should always be clearly legible). The official requirements are stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn764944.aspx). As long as the UI is responsive an not misleading for users, you won't have any problems.

Personally, I've published several apps to WP, including some with special, non-standard UIs, and got rejected quite a few times, but never because of disregarding design guidelines. Mostly, it was due to technical reasons, or the button example I stated above.